# Fullcalendar resource timeline does not show last week of the year

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying resource timeline custom view like below. The problem is last week of the year does not show and the last week of the previous year show up wrongly. Am i doing something wrong or this is a fullcalendar bug i don't know.

Sorry for my bad english. Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Thanks!

[image]

Here is my fullCalendar settings

```
{
          initialDate: moment().startOf('year')._d,
          customButtons: {
            eventFilterButton: {
              text: 'Filtrele',
              click: function(e) {

                setFilterPopupPosition({
                  top: e.clientY + window.scrollY,
                  left: e.clientX - 220,
                });
                setFilterPopupvisibility(true);
              }
            }
          },
          slotMinWidth: 40,
          showNonCurrentDates: false,
          fixedWeekCount: true,
          slotLabelFormat: [
            { month: "long"}, // top level of text
            { week: "number" } // lower level of text
          ],
          slotLabelContent: (arg) => {
            if ( Number(arg.text) ) {
              const result = getWeekOfMonth(arg.date);
              return result;
            }
          },
          height: window.innerHeight - 220,
          eventMaxStack: 5,
          scrollTimeReset: false,
          stickyHeaderDates: true,
          eventBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
          eventBorderColor: 'transparent',
          selectable: true,
          initialView: 'resourceTimelineMonths',
          locale: 'en',
          weekends: true,
          defaultView: 'resourceTimeline',
          eventContent: renderEventContent,
          views: {
            resourceTimelineMonths: {
              type: 'resourceTimeline',
              duration: { months: 12 },
              buttonText: 'Aylık Görünüm',
              slotDuration: {
                weeks: 1,
              }
            },
          },
          headerToolbar: {
            right: 'today eventFilterButton' // prev,next
          },

          resourceLabelContent: function (renderInfo) {
            return (<CalendarResourceItem resources={calendarResources.current} forceUpdateValue={forceUpdateValue} expanded={rersourceGroupExpandState.current[renderInfo.resource.id]} renderInfo={renderInfo} resourceMenuClickCallback={resourceMenuClickCallback} expandCallback={handleResourceExpand}/>)
          },
          resourceAreaWidth: '222px',
          resourceAreaHeaderContent: yearPicker,
          dayHeaderFormat: {
            day: 'short',
            weekday: 'short',
            month: 'numeric',
            week: 'numeric',
            omitCommas: true,
          },
          allDayDefault: true,
          droppable: true,
          editable: true,
          resourceGroupLabelContent: function (renderInfo) {
            console.log('resourceGroupLabelContent', renderInfo)
            return (
              <div
                className="schedule--resourceLabel"
                onClick={() => handleResourceLAbelClick(renderInfo.groupValue)}
              >
                {renderInfo.groupValue}{' '}
                {rersourceGroupExpandState.current[renderInfo.resource.id] ? (
                  <Icon rotate={180} component={IconChevronUp} />
                ) : (
                  <Icon component={IconChevronUp} />
                )}
              </div>
            )
          },
          resourceLabelDidMount: (info) => {
            setTimeout(() => {

              // console.warn('************************ resourceGroupLabelDidMount --------------------------', info)
              resourceExpanderElementList.push({
                selector: info.resource.id,
                el: info.el.querySelector('.fc-datagrid-expander'),
              })
              taskAssignmentStore.dispatch({
                type: 'SET_RESOURCE_EXPAND_LABELS',
                resourceLabels: resourceExpanderElementList,
              })
              rersourceGroupExpandState.current[info.resource.id] = false
                
            });
          },
        }
```